# How do I make a loading page while I am processing something in the backend with Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, web-applications

I have a main view function for my application. After logging in successfully this main view method is called and is expected to render the template.

But I have to perform some calculations in this view method [I am checking certain conditions about the user by making facebook graph api request.]

Thus it takes 2~4 seconds to load.

How do I show this loading scene since the template is rendered by return statement and thus is executed only when the process is complete.

Should I make 2 views , one for showing loading and the other one for calculating and keep making `AJAX` request to other view method to check if the process is complete or not ?

Comment: Do you need the result of your Graph API requests to render the template?

Comment: No! But I have to load some data about the user by graph api and scan that data for a particular condition. (This process takes place inside a loop which takes ~2-4 minutes to complete). I compute True/False for each user by this method. If True I wish to log in the user. [ but this view takes 2-4 minutes to load ). Thus I wish to implement a visual loading page while this is happening in background.

Comment: Is it 2-4 seconds or minutes?

Comment: seconds on development machine. At worst I expect this to take ~10 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should indeed make two views, one to only return the page showing the loading UI and one to perform the long task.

The second view will be called using an AJAX request made from the "loading" page. The response from the AJAX request will notify your "loading" page that it is time to move on.

You need to make sure the AJAX request's duration won't exceed the timeout of your server (with ~10 seconds, you should be fine).

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your Graph API requests in a task executed asynchronously, allowing you to return a `HttpResponse` without waiting for the task to finish.

[Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) will allow you to do just that.

You then need a way to notify your client that the asynchronous task has finished.
I see two ways to do that:

1. Making AJAX requests at regular intervals to a view that will check if the task is finished.
2. Using [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

The first approach is the simplest  but has the drawback of making a lot of useless requests and of being less reactive.

Using WebSockets on the other side will require more configuration as an external app is required (ex: [django-socketio](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio) or [swampdragon](https://github.com/jonashagstedt/swampdragon)).
If it is the only place where you need notifications from server to client, using WebSockets seems to be overkill.

Comment: To me this looks like an over play. Using additional plugins for just showing loading page while another view has returned a template?

Comment: Indeed, in facts, I just thought of a much simpler solution, I'll add an answer for it.